# Looking for Implementing Role Playing dimension in Azure Analysis Services (Tabular)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

As of now in my fact table i have around 6 Date Keys which needs to be linked to one Date Dimension.

Possible solution on table with me is:

Creating multiple date dimension and linking it with Fact Table. As this involves duplicating the data. I wanted to avoid this solution as i have around 10 Date Columns in my fact Table.

I am looking for a solution in order to reduce the redundancy of number of Tables in my Model.

Something like User-Role

Answer (score 1):

Without increasing the number of tables,  we can use the relationship which is relevant to the measures. This can be achieved by enforcing the data model to activate the relationship we need. The relationship can be moved from inactive to active in DAX using USERELATIONSHIP function. Below are the snaps showing one active and 2 inactive relationships and usage of "USERELATIONSHIP" while implementing the measures and results later.

[image: ActiveRelationship]
[image]
[image]